# ld: library not found for -lPods-AutomatorSampleApp-Illuminator clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode-6.2

While running AutomatorSampleApp.xcodeproj  , I am getting error:--

> ld: library not found for -lPods-AutomatorSampleApp-Illuminator clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: reformat your question properly

Answer (score 0):

When using illuminator for my iOS project, I had to add  `-l"Illuminator"` to Build Settings > PODS_OTHER_LDFLAGS under the Debug section.[image]